# Clang error: Duplicate Symbol

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, clang

I'm getting this error while compiling

> ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ScaleTypeDisclosureSection in
>   .../Build/Intermediates/A.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A.build/Objects-normal/i386/ScaleEditorViewController-DDFF198930F36D54.o
>   and
>   .../Build/Intermediates/A.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A.build/Objects-normal/i386/ScaleEditorViewController-DDFF198930F36D54.o
>   for architecture i386

This seems really weird because it appears that the linker is trying to link the file with itself. I have searched my entire computer and there exist only 1 .h and one .m file with that name. I've cleaned my project several times. I've tried ripping the ScaleTypeDisclosureSection class out of my app entirely, and in that case, it just gives me a duplicate symbol error for a different object in the ScaleEditorViewController file! I've checked for double imports also. I'm lost!

To clarify, there are a few classes defined in the ScaleEditorViewController.h and ScaleEditorViewController.m file. One is the view controller, the others are little helpers classes. Even if I take every class out but the main class, I still get an error.

Comment: Are you using `#include` instead of `#import`?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is now fixed. I'm not exactly sure why. I think it might have something to do with me having imported files (into Xcode) and setting their target to my test target instead of my main target. Deleting all file references and then dragging all files back into my project solved the problem.